# What is the list of HTML tags that are supported in NSAttributedString?

Tags: html, ios, nsattributedstring

I could not find where in the documentation that states which HTML tags are supported in NSAttributedString? Does anyone know what is the list? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At present the following tags are supported that I found in GitHub
(link to git page: https://github.com/johnezang/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML) I think this may help you

```
Headers H1 - H6
Paragraphs: P
Bold: B, STRONG
Italic: I, EM
Underline: U
Superscript: SUP
Subscript: SUB, e.g. e = mc2
Styling: FONT (face and color, not size). It would be great if we could support many more styles
Unordered Lists: UL, LI
Ordered Lists: OL, LI
```

Comment: i  think this may usefull to you